# How to share the same driver for step definition and other class files

Tags: cucumber

MyStepDef  {

public MyStepDef (WebDriver driver) {

```
     this.driver = Hook.getDriver();

    }
```

}

Other Class file {
   sys.out("Hi"

}

Comment: Above i have to call the method from Other Class file into my step def, when i tried call by using the i have used constructor to call hooks in both class file and step defenition

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more information about your code/directory structure/etc. . Best would be a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).